# Automatically run graphical python script on startup

Tags: unity, python, cron, startup, autostart

I have a python script that starts a fullscreen animation when run - how do i set this to start at startup in ubuntu 16.04? Other answers to the "script on startup" problem don't work - because I'm assuming they're executed before the desktop environment has a chance to start up...

I have a script called "startup.sh" that reads as:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 -s 1280x1024

source activate demo

cd ~/demo/

python run.py
```

Where the first line sets the correct resolution - the second line activates an anaconda environment, the third line changes directory (parts of the script need it to be in that directory, and the 4th line finally runs the script that launches a fullscreen graphic (using pygame, if it matters.)

How can i set this to auto run after unity finishes setting up? Thanks so much... any help or comments at all are really appreciated...

EDIT: it looks like someone here had a similar problem: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=128602

They wanted to start a pygame script on startup - and were able to do so after their desktop environment loaded by putting a call to their program in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` - I'm not using LXDE - i'm on unity, so is there an equivalent?

Comment: "Other answers to the "script on startup" problem don't work...". What don't work? What have you tried specifically?

Comment: Have you tried adding it to "startup applications" (accessible from the dash)?

Comment: @j-money I have tried adding it to "startup applications" and setting a cron job

Comment: @danzel yes - see above

Comment: you might try writing a unit file for systemd and enabling it, and in your script a hacky way might be to just tell it to sleep N to wait for the X environment. Or if I remember correctly unit files have a flag that tell them to wait for certain events?

Comment: As per a quick google search you could try `Requires=graphical.target` in the unit file??

Comment: @j-money thank you - i have never written a unit file before but i will try to and include that flag

Comment: Out of curiosity, what _does_ happen when you add it to startup applications?

Comment: @danzel it doesn't run. I've put in things like "touch test.txt" in the startup.sh script i detailed above, and it makes the empty test.txt file - so i tried piping the outputs of the different lines of the startup.sh file into different text files but they're empty when i look at them (e.g. i add a ">>somefile.txt" at the end of each line in the program detailed in my initial post).

Comment: I see you're using the `source` command, which is a bash built-in. Did you make sure your script is executed by bash? The default non-interactive shell in Ubuntu is dash, which does not support that command. Additionally, you may want to redirect stderr to that file as well: `command >> file 2>&1`

Comment: @danzel - yes, my script is executed by bash (has `#!/bin/bash` at the top). I'll try the stderr thing in one second.

Comment: @danzel - with the added >> log.txt 2>&1 at the end of each line, log.txt is 0 bytes on startup.

Comment: The `~` is probably not expanded in non-interactive mode. Try replacing it with `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like this?

```
[Unit]
Description=Start some anaconda service (?)    
Requires=graphical.target

[Service]
ExecStart=path/to/your/script
```

I personally haven't tested it, so you'll have to let me know if it works. For better reference here is the [unit file](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) page!

Also, make sure you **enable** the file when your done!

Comment: IIRC, `graphical.target` is reached before the display manager starts.

Comment: thank you for the hint - i'm trying this currently...

Comment: @danzel I honestly don't remember :/ what would you recommend so I can improve the answer?

Comment: unfortunately still not working - im guessing that it is executing before unity starts up, because the monitors aren't switched by the xrandr command (when i run the command after unity starts up it switches off one monitor and on another)

Comment: See danzel's comment